# Django admin - Add button for ForeignKey in inline

Tags: django, search, admin, inline

In a django admin screen, I would like to have the possibility to pick up en existing entry in the DB as a field of an inline zone.

My models are similar to this (forgive the nonsensical way it is design, this is just an example):

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Seller(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Association(models.Model):
  type = models.ForeignKey(Buyer)
  type = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
```

In the seller admin page, I have an inline (TabularInline) listing all the associations to a seller for that buyer.

```
class AssociationInLine(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Assignation

class BuyerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = (DevisAssignationInLine, )
```

In the field representing the seller i have a text input. Instead, I would like to click a button, which would open a search page where I can search the Sellers in the DB, click on it and that's it, it is associated to the Buyer.

How would you do that ?

Comment: How about a `raw_id_field`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields

Comment: You are totally right. I just forgot to add an Admin object for Association : [The answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/Yg1PtV_D-ME). Can you make an answer and I'll flag it as accepted. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[raw_id_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) is what you're looking for:

```
class BuyersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("association",)
```